# Selective Deployment in Azure Data Factory (ADF)?

Tags: continuous-deployment, cicd, azure-data-factory

I am using npm package based CI-CD approach for ADF. I want to selectively deploy some pipelines and datasets on prod, instead of deploying everything in repository.

Is there any powershell script where I can send list of ADF objects which I want to deploy using my CI-CD pipeline?

Instead of powershell, if there is any other way, please let me know that as well.

Comment: If my answer was helpful , You can Accept it as an Answer, so that others who encounter the same issue can find this solution and fix their problem.

Answer (score 0):

As per [official documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/continuous-integration-delivery#unsupported-features), Data factory entities depend on each other.

For example, triggers depend on pipelines, and pipelines depend on datasets and other pipelines. Selective publishing of a subset of resources could lead to unexpected behaviors and errors.

On rare occasions when you need selective publishing, consider using a hotfix.

[Steps to deploy a hotfix](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/continuous-integration-delivery-hotfix-environment#steps-to-deploy-a-hotfix)